# APNS Remote notification when app is brought to foreground

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am using remote notifications to ping IOs devices so to issue a call to my server once the application is brought to foreground (or is already in foreground).

I see is the following behaviour:

1. App is in foreground: - `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler` is called.
2. App is brought to foreground by clicking on the alert popup: -  `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler` is called.
3. App is brought to foreground by clicking on the app's icon - none of the `didReceiceRemoteNotification` (nor `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`) are called.

Since I need to make sure the device gets the ping in all of these scenarios, I must make sure option (3) works as well. Is it possible to get notified about the remote notification is this scenario?

Comment: You will get notified only if you open app by taping on notification and not by taping app icon

Comment: So I can't really rely on APNS for real time push notification? I think option (3) can occur many times

Comment: Notifications are handled by the operating system, you app can't know if a push notification is received if it isn't on the foreground or the user taps the notification. So, to your question "So I can't really rely on APNS for real time push notification?", you can rely, the push notifications are received by the operating system and shown to the user as soon as they arrive. But you can't rely on your app knowing which push notifications were read by the user unless your app was opened when they arrived or the user tapped the push notification

Comment: Agree with @jcesarmobile